# Jquery page submit returning immediately before completion

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

I am developing a Andriod app using Phonegap with jQuery mobile.  The app will submit some data to server and should wait for server response to proceed further.  Things are working fine but the page returns immediately before getting the response.

This is the sample server PHP program.  I put a sleep command to make sure the page runs for 100 seconds.

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');

for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    sleep(1);
    fwrite($fp, 'testdata');
}
fclose($fp);     

echo 'success';
```

The AJAX page submit script

```
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            var postData = $(this).serialize();
            $("#btn_login_submit",this).attr("disabled","disabled");
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'http://website.org/phonegap/save.php',
                data : postData,
            beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
            complete : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
            success : function(response){
                  alert('Success');
                }, 
                error : function(){
                  alert('Sorry, unable to connect to server');
                }
            });
            $("#btn_login_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    });
});
```

**Problem:**
Once I hit the submit button the page gets submitted and immediately it returns.  After 100 seconds I am getting the alert message as 'Success'.  I would expect that the page should show the loading image till the PHP program completes and return the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After including **async: false** now the page is returning after the AJAX return.  But now the mobile loading image is not appearing. Once the button clicked it looks like the page got hanged.  I need the page loader displayed until AJAX returns... Any idea???

Comment: Well it seems you've narrowed it down to the problem you're having as having to deal with what AJAX inherently is: **Asynchronous**.  The page isn't going to wait for the end of the function to keep on going. I would say do something else along the lines of putting the loading icon up right before the ajax call and then in success removing the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return false;` at the end of the submit function. This will prevent default submit action and you won't get response immediately. Also don't use `async:false` because it blocks ui until you get response and deprecated in jQuery 1.8+.